Metropolis Hastings chain getting stuck at high values
I'm new at implementing the Metropolis-Hastings algorithm. I'm trying to implement it for an Inverse Gamma distribution $p(x,\alpha,\beta)=\frac{\beta^\alpha}{\Gamma(\alpha)}(\frac{1}{x})^{\alpha+1} e^{\frac{-\beta}{x}}$. The problem I'm facing is that sometimes my chain gets stuck at high values. I'm using a lognormal step since the points should be always positive. Since the distribution only has expected values if $\alpha>1$, I set $x_0$ to be the maximum of the p.d.f. I tested some values for $\sigma$ and 20 or so seems good, but I only tested it for $\alpha=1,\beta=1$
What can I do to avoid that?
My code:
def Metropolis(n,sigma,alpha,beta):
    x_0=beta/(alpha+1)
    target = lambda x: 1/(x**(alpha+1))*np.exp(-beta/x)
    lognormal = lambda x,y:np.exp(-(np.log(x)-y)**2/(2*sigma**2))/(sigma*x*np.sqrt(2*np.pi))
    x=[x_0]
    for c in range(n):
        x_now=x[c]
        x_star=np.random.lognormal(x_now,sigma)
        alpha=np.min([1,(target(x_star)*lognormal(x_now,x_star))/(target(x_now)*lognormal(x_star,x_now))])
        u=np.random.uniform()
        if u<=alpha:
            x.append(x_star)
        else:
            x.append(x_now)
    ###plotting###
    x_max=np.max(x)
    fig, axs = plt.subplots(1,2)
    fig.set_figheight(10)
    fig.set_figwidth(10)
    t=np.linspace(0.01,x_max)
    axs[0].plot(x,range(n+1))
    line = axs[1].hist(x,range=[0,x_max],bins=100,density=True)
    max_hist=np.max(line[0])
    max_target=np.max(target(t))
    scale=max_hist/max_target
    axs[1].plot(t,scale*target(t))
    axs[0].grid()
    axs[1].grid()
    axs[0].set_xlim(0,x_max)
Metropolis(20000,20,1,1)

This figure shows what usually happens when I run the code. You can see that it gets stuck at high values for some time but comes back.

This one shows some bad simulations that sometimes happen

As suggested, here are the plots of the proposed values. Since $\sigma$ is large, the proposed values are often out of scale. But reducing $\sigma$ does not help either.


try recording not only the accepted values, but also the proposed ones, and overlay those over "x" on the plot.

@JohnMadden The proposed ones are usually very large (I guess because of the high $\sigma$), I'll edit with a plot.

Fitting log of the probability (log-likelihood) would be likely a significant improvement.

@RogerV. You mean tanking the log of the ratio "target * lognormal/target * lognormal"? Or taking the log of the target distribution?

Do all of your calculations on the log scale (i.e. compute lcur = logposterior(current), lprop=logposterior(proposed), then your ratio for the M-H acceptance is exp(lprop-lcur)

The function that you minimize is pdf of the Gamma distribution, $p(x)$. It is usually easier to minimize its : $\log p(x)$. Since logarithm is a monotonuous function, it has maximum at the same place. It usually improves convergence and avoids numerical errors caused by too big/small numbers.

I am also not sure I understand why you use log-normal step - since it is a step, it doesn't guarantee that you remain within the positive range (disclaimer: I didn't analyze your code.)

@RogerV. nah the proposal is from a lognormal distribution centered at the previous value.

Just arrived home, I'll try your suggestions.

Thank you for your help. The main problem was that the parameters that you set to sample from a lognormal distribution are not the mean and variance of the distribution, but of the Normal distribution that generated it. To fix it, I just had to do a transformation that's shown on the wikipidia page of the lognormal distribution. If you want your lognormal to have mean $\mu_X$ and variance $\sigma_X$ you have to choose $\mu=ln(\frac{\mu_x^2}{\mu_x^2+\sigma_x^2})$ and $\sigma^2=ln(1+\frac{\mu_x^2}{\sigma_x^2})$

I have converted your code to R (see below), and it appears to be working correctly. There are three main differences between your code and the R code below:

Your Python code uses alpha to mean two different things - you use it as a parameter value and as the acceptance probability. Even if this isn't causing issues in your code (and it may be), you probably want to avoid this.
My R code works with the log of the pdf's to generate the log acceptance probability.
My R code uses R's built-in lognormal pdf, rather than the one you provided.

Since the R program seems to be working correctly, I suspect that the sources of any anomalies you are seeing is due to one of those three things.
A final note - the value sigma=20 is probably too large, as it results in a low acceptance probability.
ln_target <- function(x,alpha,beta){
  t <- (-beta/x) - (alpha+1)*log(x)
  return(t)
}

metropolis <- function(n,sigma,alpha,beta){
  x_0 <- beta/(alpha+1)
  x <- rep(NA,n+1)
  x[1] <- x_0
  for (c in 1:n){
    x_now <- x[c]
    x_star <- exp(rnorm(n=1,mean=log(x_now),sd=sigma))
    
    ln_num <- ln_target(x_star,alpha,beta) + dlnorm(x = x_now,meanlog = log(x_star),sdlog = sigma,log=TRUE)
    ln_denom <- ln_target(x_now,alpha,beta) + dlnorm(x = x_star,meanlog = log(x_now),sdlog = sigma,log=TRUE)
    
    acc <- ln_num - ln_denom
    
    u <- log(runif(1))
    if (u<=acc){
      x[c+1] <- x_star
    }else{
      x[c+1] <- x_now
    }
  }
  return (x)
}

n <- 20000
sigma <- 20
alpha <- 1
beta <- 1

x <- metropolis(n,sigma,alpha,beta)

acceptance_rate <- 1-mean(diff(x)==0)
hist(x,breaks=100)
plot(x,type='l')


I'll look into it. I'm still having trouble choosing $\sigma$. Maybe your code can help. Thank you!

No problem. $\sigma=3$ was giving me an acceptance rate in the 45% range.
